# Avalonia ListBox shifts text by 1 pixel when hovering a ListBoxItem for the first time

Tags: listbox, .net-7.0, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am experiencing this issue with even the simplest of list boxes, take this for example:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="TheListBox"  Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" >
  <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1"/>
  <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2"/>
  <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3"/>
  <ListBoxItem Content="Item 4"/>
</ListBox>
```

There seems to be a strange phenomenon where when the list first renders in, when I hover over each item for the first time, some items will shift to the left by 1 pixel. It happens to say, 90% of the elements in the list.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about in a real ListBox from my application
[image]

Once I hover over the first iron sword in the list, all of the text shifts left by 1. Interestingly enough, the images do not move.

How do I stop this from happening? I am using Avalonia version 11.0.2, targeting Net 7, and building a Desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with other example Avalonia projects, I seemed to have solved the issue by switching the global theme to from Fluent to Simple.

Issue does not occur using Simple, and still happens when I switch back to Fluent.

Comment: Visit https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia and search the default style xaml file(switch  the tag to the version you use)